# What is "Refreshing Models " in Laravel Eloquent please help me out to understand this

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner in Laravel and I do not clearly understand about Refreshing Models from Laravel Documentation please give an example to understand this feature.
I have to know about where we use fresh() and where we use refresh method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models), when you call `fresh()` a new database query is launched and the model attribute change to those from the database. example

```
$user = User::find(1);
echo $user->first_name; // "Punit"
$user->first_name = "Not Punit";
echo $user->first_name; // "Not Punit"
$user->fresh();
echo $user->first_name; // "Punit"
```

The `refresh()` method does the same thing but without the call for the database, instead it will reset the **attributes** from the **originalAttributes** it stored from the first database call.
Further more, `refresh()` will also launch `refresh()` on the loaded relation of that model instance.